# What's the .NET equivalent to sending a file using postman

Tags: json, rest, postman

I have a working postman call in which I send a json file.
The json file is sent using form-data and I import the file using the file dropdown in the formdata parameters
[image]

Now I try to implement the same call in .NET using the HTTPClient and StreamContent classes:

```
ms.Position = 0;
StreamContent sc = new StreamContent(ms);
formdataContent.Add(sc, "data");
```

When I now send the formdataContent to the interface, the interface complains that the JSON is in textformat rather than file format.

Edit: Had the same results using ByteArrayContent

Answer (score 0):

```
var client = new RestClient("https://localhost:5001/api/v1/user/uploadphoto");
// client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddFile("image", "9TbdT39_c/test.csv");
request.AddParameter("name", "ram");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for though

Comment: Can you check again

Comment: For images it works fine using streamContent.
I have troubles sending JSON Files as file- instead of string-content